# How to completely disable sound in externally loaded SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, ads

In my application I need to play externally loaded third-party SWFs (ads) without sound. What I've done so far:

- using SoundTransform set volume to 0;
- do this every frame so if the ad tries to reset the volume, I will set it back to 0.

Most of the time it works. However, occasionally there are ads that still play sound.

I suspect those ads do the same trick and here we have a race condition - who is the last to change the volume.

Is there any way to totally disable sound for the loaded SWF? Is there any way to prevent such race condition?

Here is my code:

```
    function onAdStart():void
    {
        setMasterSound(0);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
    }

    function tick( e:Event ):void {
        setMasterSound(0);
    }

    function SetMasterSound(volume:Number):void
    {
        var masterSound:SoundTransform;
        if(SoundMixer.soundTransform.volume != volume)
        {
            masterSound = new SoundTransform();
            masterSound.volume = volume;
            SoundMixer.soundTransform = masterSound;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note for that type of code. I use a SoundManager type of class (singleton) that is global even for loaded swf. That way I stay in total control of all sound playing and can set all volumes correctly regardless of sound being played within a swf or not. All sounds have to be played via that class for it to work but all those issues disappear with it.

Comment: @BotMaster, but in your case you control the loaded SWFs as well, right? I mean, you code the loaded SWFs so they use your global class?

Comment: So if you set the soundTransform property of the Sprite that you load the swf into is the loaded swf working around that?

Comment: I found another answer that better describes what i was asking. Does loading the swf and controlling the sound in the way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3490382/4080444) not stop the loaded swf from being heard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 load, play and mute external swf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490324/as3-load-play-and-mute-external-swf)

Comment: @aleksey-linetskiy Hi Aleksey, have you found a solution for that? I fight with a same problem global sound mixer doesn't help (because an ad overrides it), even walking trough display list and setting 0 volume on every sprite's sound transform doesn't help (ad could use sound transform detached from the display list, videos have sound transform on their net stream, which isn't accessible from loader SWF).